# Reusing Stack with Group when nesting Navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v6

Using React Navigation 6, [in the documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators#best-practices-when-nesting), they recommend you use Groups to minimize nested navigators.

However I'm not sure how to do that in this example, using a nested Stack in a Tab Navigator:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { View, Button } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

function FeedScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Button
        title="Go to Settings"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Settings')}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

function ProfileScreen() {
  return <View />;
}

function SettingsScreen() {
  return <View />;
}

const FeedStack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function FeedStackScreen() {
  return (
    <FeedStack.Navigator>
      <FeedStack.Screen name="Feed" component={FeedScreen} />
      {/* other screens */}
    </FeedStack.Navigator>
  );
}

const ProfileStack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function ProfileStackScreen() {
  return (
    <ProfileStack.Navigator>
      <ProfileStack.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} />
      {/* other screens */}
    </ProfileStack.Navigator>
  );
}

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

function HomeTabs() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
      <Tab.Screen name="Feed" component={FeedStackScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileStackScreen} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}

const RootStack = createNativeStackNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <RootStack.Navigator>
        <RootStack.Screen
          name="Home"
          component={HomeTabs}
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
        />
        <RootStack.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
      </RootStack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

When I reuse the Stack so only one is used in the Tab Navigator it still works:

```
const TabStack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function FeedStackScreen() {
  return (
    <TabStack.Navigator>
      <TabStack.Screen name="Feed" component={FeedScreen} />
      {/* other screens */}
    </TabStack.Navigator>
  );
}

function ProfileStackScreen() {
  return (
    <TabStack.Navigator>
      <TabStack.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} />
      {/* other screens */}
    </TabStack.Navigator>
  );
}

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

function HomeTabs() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
      <Tab.Screen name="Feed" component={FeedStackScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileStackScreen} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}
```

However when I try to use Group like this:

```
const TabStack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function FeedStackScreen() {
  return (
    <TabStack.Group>
      <TabStack.Screen name="Feed" component={FeedScreen} />
      {/* other screens */}
    </TabStack.Group>
  );
}

function ProfileStackScreen() {
  return (
    <TabStack.Group>
      <TabStack.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} />
      {/* other screens */}
    </TabStack.Group>
  );
}

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

function HomeTabs() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
      <TabStack.Navigator>
        <Tab.Screen name="Feed" component={FeedStackScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileStackScreen} />
      </TabStack.Navigator>
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}
```

I get the error `a navigator can only contain 'screen' 'group' or 'react.fragment'` because you can't have a navigator inside another without writing it in the `component`.

Is there a way to use Group here or is the correct way to write `<TabStack.Navigator></TabStack.Navigator>` for each of the "Groups"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is that `Group` is a component returned by the `navigator`. If we create a JSX component that returns that group instead, then this is technically not a `Group` anymore but its own JSX component.

This is an unsolved problem in `react-native-navigation` and is discussed [in this GitHub issue](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/9578), but has apparently no satisfying solution other than an ugly hack.

We can call the functional component inline.

```js
function CustomGroupComponent() {
  return <Tab.Group>
          <Tab.Screen ... />
          <Tab.Screen ... />
      </Tab.Group>
}

export const Tabs = (props) => {

  return (

     <Tab.Navigator ...>
         <Tab.Screen ...>
         {CustomGroupComponent()}
     </Tab.Navigator>
  )
}
```

Thus in summary, there is no pretty solution. The trick is to call the functional component as a function inline using `{CustomGroupComponet()}`.

**Remarks:** I would consider this as an anti-pattern, but there is no other solution in the current version as far as I am concerned.

Comment: This works fine